# Pandas df re-ordering columns seems to work within a loop, but doesn't. What the heck am I missing?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

So I'm completely perplexed as to why this is happening:

I have 8 different Pandas dataframes, with same columns.  I want to rearrange the columns equally on all of them.  So I created a list and tried this:

```
original_cols = [1, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
new_cols = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1]

list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3...., df8]

for df in list_of_dfs:
    df = df[new_cols]
```

When I look at any of the dataframes, I still get the old column order, why? I inserted a print statement as below, and the loop does what I want:

```
for df in list_of_dfs:
    print (df.columns.tolist())
    df = df[new_cols]
    print (df.columns.tolist())

Output (for df1):
[1, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1]
```

I can just write out all manually, but thought a simple loop would be better but can't get it to work.  I must be missing some fundamental understanding of loops or something.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Current solution:

````
df1 = df1[new_cols]
df2 = df2[new_cols]
.
.
```
````

Comment: When you start the iteration with `for df in list_of_dfs`, df refers to an element of the list. When you do `df = df[new_cols]` you create a new variable named df that has nothing to to with the first element of that list. In the second iteration this will be overwritten again, and then again. Please see [this article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) to see how names work in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `df = df[new_cols]` it is not updating the DataFrame in the list. Try this:

```
size_ = len(list_of_dfs)
for idx in range(size_):
    list_of_dfs[idx] = list_of_dfs[idx][new_cols]
```

Now idx will represent an index location in `list_of_dfs` and you can just update the DataFrame columns at each index.

Comment: Still not working.  I wrote exactly as you did and while within the loop the columns are re-ordered, the dfs are not updated after the loop ends.  What else am I missing?

Comment: Oh I understand you want to be be able to call df, df1, outside of the list with the updated values this wasn't clear before, but the list does not contain the original `DataFrames`, but rather a copy. I don't think you can accomplish this functionality with a list (that I know of). If you notice your `list_of_dfs` is updated with the correct column values and you can access a given `DataFrame` by the index.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a copy of the `DataFrame` object. If you need to swap variable names in the global scope (not recommended), you may use `globals` to refer to the object itself.

```
import re
for df in [name for name in globals() if re.findall('df\d+', name)]:
    globals()[df] = globals()[df][new_cols]
```

Comment: Yeah, as you mentioned, I don't think I want to mess with anything global.  There has to be a way to do this operation on df objects through a loop, rather than repeating (typing) essentially the same operation multiple times, as I'm doing now.